# is there an LS for users?

Tags: command-line, permissions, files, users, groups

I want to see what files and folders a user on my system has permission to. 
I am an admin, on the system. how do I get more information about what files and folders a user can access?

Command line solutions preferred, I am on remote ssh to the host.

Answer (score 0):

Find files owned by a user with the following command:

```
find directory-location -user <username>
```

...where `<username>` is replaced by the name of the user that you are filtering the search results by. You can filter the search further as follows:

```
find directory-location -user <username> -name <file-name>
```

- `directory-location`: Locate files or directories in this directory location.
- `-user <username>`: Find the files or directories that belong to this user.
- `-name <file-name>`: File name or pattern.

<sub>**Source:** [Linux / Unix Find all the files owned by a particular user / group](https://web.archive.org/web/20200505132724/https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-do-i-find-all-the-files-owned-by-a-particular-user-or-group/)</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the user name is `rick` then try these two commands:

```
$ sudo ls -al /var/cache/ldconfig/aux-cache

-rw------- 1 root root 82579 Oct  1 16:51 /var/cache/ldconfig/aux-cache

$ sudo -u rick ls -al /var/cache/ldconfig/aux-cache

ls: cannot access '/var/cache/ldconfig/aux-cache': Permission denied
```

`ls` works for `sudo` as default user `root` in the first example. But when `sudo` (**S**ubstitute **U**ser **Do**) is the user `rick` permission is denied.

Answer (score 0):

You can search files by their permissions using the find command and the -perm option though if you intend to check for owner and group level access you will need to use the -user and -group parameters also.

You can find a full description of these options in the find manual page to determine which would work best for your use case:

```
man find
```

But for an example lets say you have a user named bob in the group users the following command would find all files bob has read access to as owner, group member or otherwise:

```
find -perm /444 -user bob -group users
```

The / before the permissions there allow matches if any one of the user bob, the group users or the default everyone has at least read permissions for the file that is to say it would match things like a 600 file owned by bob as his user account has read permissions to it even though the others don't.

There are other prefixes that allow for fine tuning the permissions you want to search for, but again this would be a long winded explaination to get into them all now without knowing your specific needs and the manual page already documents these.

Also I feel it is important to mention here that permissions do get a bit more complex than this due to multiple group memberships etc. Tools like this are a good way to get a quick overview of the files a user may have access to but don't assume the output is comprehensive if security is your end goal I would suggest testing is the best way to be sure in that case.